# jquery $.each() to for loop conversion

Tags: jquery, loops

Hi guys I'm new to JS so my question seems to be trivial for you.
I want to rewrite $.each() loop to for loop

Here is my code:

```
  var students=[
  {
  "roll": 101,
  "name": "Ben",
  "emailId":"ben@gmail.com"
  },
  {
  "roll": 102,
  "name": "Ian",
  "emailId":"ian@gmail.com"
  },
  {
  "roll": 103,
  "name": "Caroline",
  "emailId":"carol@gmail.com"
  }
  ];
  $.each(students,function(i,v){
    $('p.listofstud').append(v.roll + " " + v.name + " " + v.emailId + "<br/>");
  });
```

When I rewrite it i got [object Object] all properties are in one line (I prefer each three properties in one line).

```
  for (var i=0,len=students.length;i<len;i++) {
    for (var property in students) {
        $('p.listofstud').append(students[property] + " ");
     } 
  }
```

Can you help me please, thx in advance :)

Comment: This will help you, http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/yu8b1v28/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referencing your `students` array in the for loop, you should be referencing `students[i]`, just as in the append parameter list should be `students[i][property]`

```
for (var i = 0, len = students.length; i < len; i++){
    for (var key in students[i]){
        $('p.listofstud').append(students[i][key] + " ");
    } 
    $('p.listofstud').append("<br/>");
}
```

At the end of each loop you'll want to add a linebreak, as that will give you the desired format of having each students' parameters in a seperate row.

The problem with the original `in students` form was that you were trying to get the keys in the array of students, and not the array of one given student.